# where to store data on client side in apollo graphql?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, graphql

Let's say I have two components (A and B) that rely on the same data.

Component A is connected to graphql using apollo's graphql HOC and gets `players` array from the server.

Component B also relies on the same `players` array.

How am I supposed to pass that data (`players` array) from Component A to B? Using redux and connecting both Component A and B to it? Or by connecting Component B to apollo's graphql HOC and sending again that same query but this time for Component B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use query your GraphQL endpoint twice in both Component A & B. The first query will get the data from your endpoint and second query will probably get updated from the Apollo Client store